# A href link is empty but the servlet is redirecting itself to home page.how it is done ?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

//inboxservlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name=request.getParameter("uname");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("welcome "+name);
    out.println("<a href='SentItems?uname="+name+" '>sent items</a>");
    out.println("<a href=''>Logout</a>");
}
```

**If i click logout it redirects to login page.Help me with this**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Proper way to logout is below way:

```
out.println("<a href="LogoutServlet">Logout</a>")
```

You have to create a servlet to call logout properly:

```
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {  
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                                throws ServletException, IOException {  
            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();  

            request.getRequestDispatcher("loginPage.jsp").include(request, response);  

            HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
            session.invalidate();  

            out.print("You are successfully logged out!");  

            out.close();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 out.println("<a href=''>Logout</a>");
```

I believe your javascript code must be binding the event during page load time. See related javascript code.